# Communication between Java Swing Application and Leap Motion Listener

Tags: java, swing, leap-motion

I want to know how I can do a communication between the Java Swing Application and between my leap motion listener.

Because I want that in my application when I click on a button I can change a number with the number of finger see by the leap motion.

I have one Java Swing application :

```
public class KidCountingFrame extends JFrame
```

And one Leap Motion Runnable:

```
public class LeapMouse implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        CustomListener l = new CustomListener();
        Controller c = new Controller();
        c.addListener(l);
    }
}
```

Which is launching a Leap Motion Listener... :

```
public class CustomListener extends Listener
```

Maybe I have to use a design pattern ?

*** UPDATE : ***

I try to applied the ProgressBarDemo on my project and to follow explications.

But one error happens when I put the listener in the SwingWorker constructor :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1443" java.lang.NullPointerException: null upcall object
```

Here my updated code :

```
public class PanelLeapFingers  extends JPanel implements ActionListener,
PropertyChangeListener 
{
      private JButton digitDisplayButton;
      private Task task;

      class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>
      {

            public Task()
            {
                try
                {
                    NbFingersListener l = new NbFingersListener();
                    Controller c = new Controller();
                    c.addListener(l);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Void doInBackground() 
            {
                // In background :
                // Find how digit fingers are shown by the user
                int progress = 0;
                //setProgress(????); //I don't really know how call the listener here
                setProgress(5); //Here it's just to make a test

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void done() 
            {
              Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
              digitDisplayButton.setEnabled(true);
              setCursor(null); // turn off the wait cursor
            }
    }

      public PanelLeapFingers()
      {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        digitDisplayButton = new JButton("?");
        digitDisplayButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        digitDisplayButton.setActionCommand("start");
        digitDisplayButton.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(digitDisplayButton);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
      {
        digitDisplayButton.setEnabled(false);
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
        task = new Task();
        task.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        task.execute();
      }

      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("progress" == evt.getPropertyName()) {
          int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
          digitDisplayButton.setText(progress+"");
        }
      }

}
```

I'm not sure to be on the good way and I don't understand how I can receive information from my listener in my setProgress( ) function.

***EDIT :*** 
   *Solution* : Finally I have decide to use a Singleton Model to communicate between the listener and the Java Swing APP. I save all informations when the Listener is working in the Singleton Model and I recover the information that I need in the Java Swing APP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/java/devguide/Sample_Tutorial.html), the `Listener` will be called asynchronously, typically from another thread. To avoid blocking the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), create your `Listener` in the constructor of a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and arrange for your `doInBackground()` implementation to `publish()` frames of interest; `process()` can then handle these frames on the event dispatch thread.

Alternatively, poll the `Controller` at a suitable rate in the `ActionListener` of  [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: Thanks for help, these informations put me more on the good way, but I've some troubles in link with this situation (see the update).

Comment: I'm not sure how your `NbFingersListener` communicates with the worker. You may want to try polling the `Controller` in `doInBackground()`; it's OK to `sleep()` there to get a useable rate.

Comment: I have resolved the problem with a Singleton Model present in the LeapMotionListener and in the doInBackground() of the SwingWorker of my FingerPanel. Thx a lot.